# Formation theory in a class of locally finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question**: Does an $\mathcal{L}$ group contain a $(n,p)$-projector for arbitrary positive integers $n$ and primes $p$?

I know that this should be true, but I cannot prove it. Do you have any suggestion?

**Definitions**

Let $G$ be a locally finite group and let $p$ be a prime.

We define $O_p(G)$ to be the subgroup generated by all normal $p$-subgroups of $G$. We set also $O_{p'}(G/O_p(G))=O_{pp'}(G)/O_{p}(G)$.

If $O_{pp'}(G)=G$ we say that $G$ has $p$-length $1$.

If $O_{pp'}(G)<G$ and $O_{pp'}(G/O_{pp'}(G))=G/O_{pp'}(G)$ we say that $G$ has $p$-length $2$.

And so on...

We say that $G\in \mathcal{L}$ iff it is a countable locally finite, locally soluble group satisfying the minimal condition on $q$-subgroups for each prime $q$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $p$ a prime. A subgroup $M$ of $G$ is said to be an $(n,p)$-**projector** if, whenever $K\trianglelefteq H$, $M\leq H$, and $H/K$ has $p$-length $n$, it follows that $H=KM$.